# Can I programmatically hide markers in a dynamic layer in Google Map API v3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I would like to dynamically use javascript to hide some markers in a dynamic layer embedded on top of a normal map with Google Maps API v3.

My code generally looks like this:

```
function init_form() {
    document.getElementById('change_select_element').addEventListener('change', function () {
        // Somehow hide some markers based on user input.
    });
}

var map;

function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20, -121)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    // The example layer I use here lacks markers, but the one I use will have some.
    var layer = new google.maps.visualization.DynamicMapsEngineLayer({
        layerId: '06673056454046135537-08896501997766553811',
        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        clickable: true
    });

    init_form();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I'm wondering if there's some DOM element representation of a marker that I could conveniently latch onto and apply CSS styles like `display:none` to. For instance, it'd be nice to be able to hide any of the markers on a map like this one dynamically: http://maps.google.com/gallery/details?id=zah9NJ0CwqNw.kAx_b7jm9Uz0&hl=en

Comment: whats wrong with `marker.setMap(null);` ?

Comment: What about `marker.setVisible(false)`?